# Error: The dbplyr package is required to communicate with database backends

Tags: r, dplyr, dbplyr

I am new to R and learning R from sources.

I am trying to use the dplyr package for connecting to the database.

I am trying out the following tutorial, and getting this error

https://github.com/ujjwalkarn/DataScienceR/blob/master/Intro%20to%20dplyr/7-databases.R

I am using RStudio for running the tutorials on Linux Platform.

```
> hflights_db <- src_sqlite("hflights.sqlite3", create = TRUE)
Error: The dbplyr package is required to communicate with database backends.
```

Comment: According to dplyr's documentation, as of dplyr 0.6.0, a number of databse and SQL functions moved from `dplyr` to `dbplyr`. `src_sqlite` now checks whether the `dbplyr` package is installed, & returns this error when it's not. Try installing the package?

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear. Run `install.packages("dbplyr")` if you want to use dplyr with database back ends. The tutorial was probably written with an out-of-data version of dplyr.

Answer (score 1):

Easy fix: install the **[dbplyr](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=dplyr)** package.